# Angular translate displays [object object] instead of translation

Tags: angular, translation, ngfor

I am all new to angular, but need to translate an array. Without translation everything is working

```
<cds-select class="test-input"
                style="--font-size: 18px;">
      <label>Operator</label> 
      <select class="test-operator"
              [(ngModel)]="test.operator">
        <option *ngFor="let op of operators"
                [ngValue]="op">
          {{op }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </cds-select>
```

the operators look like this:
`readonly operators = ['test1','test2', 'test3'];`
and in en.json:

```
"bla": {
"test": {
     "op": ["translation1", "translation2", "translation3"]
}}
```

if I now put insteat of
`{{op }}`
`{{'bla.test.op' | translate }}`
I get [object object] for each test. Or is this the wrong place to do the translation?